# PLS-00103: Encountered Symbol DECLARE/EOF when trying to increment values with a sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql, pls-00103

I'm working on a procedure that will declare a variable, take the value from a procedure that increments, and inserts that value along with other parameters into a table. I thought I had it all worked out, but then I got hit with PLS-00103: Encountered symbol "DECLARE" and Encountered symbol "end-of-file". I feel like I'm so close, so any help would be majorly appreciated! Thank you!

```
create or replace procedure Order_Create(date_order string, cust_id char, total float, employ_id number)
is
DECLARE NewKey;
BEGIN
NewKey := order_auto_inc.nextval;
UPDATE Progressive_Keys set Order_Limit = NewKey;
insert into ORDERS VALUES (Progressive_Keys.Order_Limit, to_date(date_order, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), cust_id, total, employ_id);
commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `declare` it's not needed in a stored procedures (as [documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54)).

A variable [declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-568AC23F-1BC3-444E-855E-BF2EC4EEB14B) needs a data type.

As the parameter `order_date` is supposed to be a date, it should be declared with that type.

You can't access the column `order_limit` outside of a statement that uses the table `progressive_keys` so you need to use the variable in the insert statement as well.

It's also good coding practice to always list the target columns in an INSERT statement (note that I just invented some column names for the `orders` table you will have to adjust them to reflect the real names in your table)

```
create or replace procedure Order_Create(date_order date, cust_id varchar, total float, employ_id number)
is
  NewKey number;
BEGIN
  NewKey := order_auto_inc.nextval;
  UPDATE Progressive_Keys set Order_Limit = NewKey;
  insert into ORDERS (some_key, order_date, customer_id, total, employee_id)
  VALUES (newkey, date_order, cust_id, total, employ_id);
  commit;
END;
```

The UPDATE looks a bit strange as it will update **all** rows in the thable `progressive_keys` not just one row.

Comment: While very seldom seen "string" actually is a valid pl/sql data type; it is defined in package STANDARD as "subtype string is varchar2;"  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb6ef86e0231746ccf893cdd9e2652b7) using it.

Comment: @Belayer: wow. I have been working with PL/SQL for over 20 years and never new that ;)

Comment: Yea, like I said it's rare. After close to 20 years, it still amazes me that I still come across little gems like that every now and then.